# How to get sender IP of a desired broadcast address:port combination?

Tags: linux, udp, broadcast

I see some broadcast packets on Wireshark that I'd like to be able to check on using what would hopefully be a simple Linux command-line utility.  It would look something like this:

```
getsenders bcast_IP port timeout
```

and it would simply print each new sender IP encountered during the timeout period.

For example:

```
getsenders 192.168.0.255 12345 0.150
```

or (alternatively)

```
getsenders 192.168.0.0/8 12345 0.150
```

would listen for broadcast packets sent to 192.168.0.255:12345, then print each unique sender encountered.  An alternate approach would listed for any broadcast senders on a specified interface.

Unfortunately, my socket-fu is weak.  What I do know is that the program must run with root permissions (suid) to listen on a broadcast socket.

I've put in lots of time (days) trying to do this from Python, but it looks like that route will require using a raw socket and parsing the packets (a packet sniffer, ugh!).  I also looked at using socat/netcat (via an execute-only suid bash script) but also got nowhere.

Is there some simple Linux code available that would do this for me?  I don't care what the tool or source language is, so long as it can be set suid-root and run from the command line.

BTW, I have a simple Python solution that works under MS Windows but dies under Linux:

```
myip = <IP address of local interface to listen on>
p = <broadcast port>
timeout = 0.150    # 150 ms
addresses = {}

if "windows" in sys.platform.tolower():
    # Create the broadcast reception socket
    bsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    bsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    bsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    bsock.settimeout(timeout)
    bsock.bind((myip, p))
    while True: # Look for all senders
        try:
            __, address = bsock.recvfrom(1024)   # Don't care about payload
        except BaseException, e:
            break   # Nothing found
        else:   # A desired broadcast packet was detected
            if address[0] not in addresses:
                addresses[address[0]] = 1
            else:
                addresses[address[0]] += 1
                if addresses[address[0]] >= 3:
                    break   # Go until timeout or any sender is seen 3 times
        finally:
            bsock.close()
            bsock = None
            print(', '.join([k for k in addresses]))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also added an alias to the interface with an IP address in the subnet of the broadcast address.  So if I'm seeing packets sent to 192.168.0.155, I'd add an alias with a free address in the range 192.168.0.1 through 192.168.0.254.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? recvfrom() provides the sender address. The rest is just programming.

Comment: My bad: I should have emphasized that I need a cross-platform solution that works on at least Windows 7+ and Linux.  The problem was that either the bind would fail, or nothing would be received, even though the packets are arriving at the interface.

Comment: Changed title to reflect that I don't care about the language used.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading and testing many examples, I finally got it working, then bisected and combined the code until I had a minimal difference that worked on both platforms.

It came down to just one line: Linux must bind to the specific broadcast address (as root), where Windows can bind to the local interface address (as a normal user) where the broadcast packets are expected to arrive.

Here's the revised code snippet:

```
bcast_addr = <IP addr of broadcast: Must end with at least one '.255'>
myip = <IP addr of local interface receiving from bcast_addr>
p = <broadcast port>
timeout = 0.150    # 150 ms
addresses = {}

# Create the broadcast reception socket
bsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
bsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
bsock.settimeout(timeout)
if "windows" in sys.platform.tolower():
    bsock.bind((myip, p))
elif os.getuid() == 0:  # Must be root for Linux!
    bsock.bind((bcast_addr, p))
while True: # Look for all senders
    try:
        __, address = bsock.recvfrom(1024)   # Don't care about payload
    except BaseException, e:
        break   # Nothing found
    else:   # A desired broadcast packet was detected
        if address[0] not in addresses:
            addresses[address[0]] = 1
        else:
            addresses[address[0]] += 1
            if addresses[address[0]] >= 3:
                break   # Go until timeout or any sender is seen 3 times
    finally:
        bsock.close()
        bsock = None
        print(', '.join([k for k in addresses]))
```

Comment: This is one of the few cases where I believe Windows may have done something 'better' than Linux.  While promiscuous interface and full broadcast binding (255.255.255.255) may fairly be restricted to root, normal users should be permitted to bind to restricted broadcast addresses (where at least the first octet is not 255).